# Learning to speak without thinking about grammar

Tags: learning-methods, self-learning, greek

I recently started learning (modern) Greek. As this is the first time I've tried to learn a second language, I have a question about learning to speak more naturally. Because Greek has such a different grammatical structure compared to English, whenever I try to speak a sentence I find myself thinking through the grammar in my head and then saying the sentence. At such an early stage, this process does slow me down. So, my question is: should I focus on thinking through what I'm going to say now, and expect that someday (after lots of practice) the grammar will become second nature?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why learn English grammar first? Just gets in the way](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/3979/why-learn-english-grammar-first-just-gets-in-the-way)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same struggle when I was learning English. I did was using the language 24/7. I was thinking in my head in English. I changed language settings to English on my phone, laptop and anything that I could change. Also, I watched a lot of reality shows and tv shows to learn how people speak, and I repeated whatever phrases they said. Also, I was hanging out with native English speakers. It takes time but eventually you will get there.